# "You don't have [ ] in your PATH," but is in [echo $PATH] (Linux)

Tags: linux, path, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to install the github-pages ruby gem on Linux Mint for use with jekyll.

After running `sudo gem install github-pages` I get:

> WARNING:  You don't have /home/max/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH,
>   gem executables will not run. Building native extensions.  This could
>   take a while... 
>   ERROR:  Error installing github-pages:    ERROR: Failed
>   to build gem native extension.

The curious thing is that my path, as printed by `echo $PATH` and by `sudo echo $PATH` both include

> /home/max/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin

So how do I end up with that warning that it is not in my PATH?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any spaces around the path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I opened up my .bashrc file in gedit and confirmed there's no space in the path entered in the line "export PATH=$PATH:/home/max/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo PATH=$PATH command
```

It is possible that sudo is scrubbing your path environment variable.

Also if you want to check the path that command with sudo sees run this instead, otherwise $PATH gets extrapolated by current shell.

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Comment: hey thanks. Running [sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'] I do not see .../ruby/2.3.0/bin in my path, so it's not in my path when run in bash. How do I fix this and sync the PATH that bash sees with the PATH from my .bashrc profile?

Comment: Try `sudo PATH=$PATH gem install github-pages` ?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know why sudo echo $PATH and sudo bash echo $PATH reference different PATH environment variables?